# Why is this UPDATE query not working on php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Hi I am struggling to see why this isn't updating the database. It reloads the page directed to by the `HEADER` but does not update the any field. Any help would be grealty appreaciated.

**Update Form**

```
 <?php
    include("../script/dbconnect.php");
    include("../script/addprodcat.php");

    $post = get_posts($_GET['id']);

    if ( isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['price'], $_POST['sale'], $_POST['picture'], $_POST['category']) ) {
    $errors = array();

        $name = trim($_POST['name']);
        $description = trim($_POST['description']);

        if ( empty($name) ) {
            $errors[] = 'You need to supply a title';
        }   else if ( strlen($name) > 255 ) {
        $errors[] = 'Title cannot be longer than 255 characters';
        }

        if ( empty($description) ) {
        $errors[] = 'You need to supply text';
        }

        if ( empty($price) ) {
        $errors[] = 'You need to supply text';
        }

        if ( empty($sale) ) {
        $errors[] = 'You need to supply text';
        }

        if ( empty($picture) ) {
        $errors[] = 'You need to supply text';
    }

    if (! category_exists('id', $_POST['category']) ) {
    $errors[] = 'Category does not exist';

    }

    if ( empty($errors) ) {
    edit_product($_GET['id'], $name, $description, $price, $sale, $picture, $_POST['category']);
    header("Location: ../admin/edit_products.php?id={$post[0]['post_id']}");
    die();
    }
}
?>
<div style="width:100%; height:150px; background-color:white;"><span style="font-family:saxMonoRegular; letter-spacing:2px; display:block; font-size:4.5em; text-align:center; padding-top:15px;"> Edit <?php echo $post[0]['name']; ?> </span></div>

<div class="link" style="width:100%; background-color:#ccc;">

<form action="" method="post">

<?php
if ( isset($errors) && ! empty($errors) ) {
echo '<ul><li>', implode('</li><li>', $errors), '</li></ul>';
}
?>

<label for="name">Title</label>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $post[0]['name']; ?>"><br/>
<label for="price">Price</label>
<input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $post[0]['price']; ?>"><br/>
<label for="sale">Sale</label>
<input type="text" name="sale" value="<?php echo $post[0]['sale']; ?>"><br/>
<label for="picture">Picture</label>
<input type="text" name="picture" value="<?php echo $post[0]['picture']; ?>"><br/>


<label for="description">Description</label>
<textarea  name="description" rows="15" cols="50"><?php echo $post[0]['description']; ?></textarea><br/>


<label for="prod_id">Category</label>
<select name="prod_id">
<?php
foreach ( get_categories() as $category ) {
$selected = ( $category['name'] == $post[0]['name'] ) ? " selected" : '';
?>

<option value="<?php echo $category['id']; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>> <?php echo $category['name']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select><br/>

<input class="button-link" type="submit" value="Edit Post">
</form>

</div>
```

**addprodcat.php**

```
function edit_product($id, $prod_id, $prod_sub_id, $name, $description, $price, $sale, $picture, $category) {

      $id           = (int) $id;  
      $prod_id      = (int) $prod_id;
      $prod_sub_id  = (int) $prod_sub_id;
      $name         = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
      $description  = mysql_real_escape_string($description);
      $price        = mysql_real_escape_string($price);
      $sale         = mysql_real_escape_string($sale);
      $picture      = mysql_real_escape_string($picture);
      $category = (int) $category;


      mysql_query("UPDATE `products` SET 
      `cat_id`     = {$category},
      `prod_id`         = {$prod_id},
      `prod_sub_id `    = '{$prod_sub_id}',
      `name`            = '{$name}',
      `description`     = '{$description}',
      `price`           = '{$price}',
      `sale`            = '{$sale}',
      `picture`         = '{$picture}'
      WHERE `id`        = {$id}");
    echo mysql_error();
    }
```

Comment: You should `echo` the generated query string and show it here, also: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your update form passes only 7 parameters to the `edit_products` function; this function, however, expects 9.

```
edit_product($_GET['id'], $name, $description, $price, $sale, $picture, $_POST['category']);
```

...

```
function edit_product($id, $prod_id, $prod_sub_id, $name, $description, $price, $sale, $picture, $category)
```

You need to pass `$prod_id` and `$prod_sub_id` as well.

As an extra note, it's worth commenting out any redirects when debugging code as any (non-fatal) errors/warnings that would otherwise be shown are missed.

Comment: Thanks alot that works now but On another note, if you dont mind, it is not picking up the values of price, sale and picture and when I remove the `$errors = array();` script it processes the script but leaves these fields blank. Obviously it is not picking up the field from the form but I cant see where....

Comment: You haven't done `$price = trim($_POST['price']);`, etc. like you have with `$description`.

Comment: so obvious now. THanks Michael. You are star!

Answer (score 0):

Number of function parameters differ. The function expects 9 but you provided 7.

This is a common user error that happens in lengthy lines.

Use the coding standard like this:

```
function edit_product(
    $id, 
    $prod_id, 
    $prod_sub_id, 
    $name, 
    $description, 
    $price, 
    $sale, 
    $picture, 
    $category
) {
    /*function code */
}
```

Follow same standard  when you 'call' the function too.